Calculate damping matrice
I need help understanding the dfdv matrix and how to calculate it. I need to compute the dfdv matrix for the springs. I'm trying to follow these notes here but I still don't understand, why it's mentioned that I need a 3x3 matrix

In my code I'm applying Bij

Here's the code I have right now
// Construct the dfdv matrices per spring
void ParticleSystem::dfdv()
{
    Eigen::Matrix3f dfdv = Eigen::Matrix3f::Zero();
    for (Spring* spring : m_springs)
    {
        Particle* particle1 = spring->particles[0];
        Particle* particle2 = spring->particles[1];

        Eigen::Vector3f distance = particle2->x - particle1->x;
        Eigen::Vector3f normalizedDistance = distance / normalizedDistance.norm();;
        
        dfdv += spring->b * (normalizedDistance * normalizedDistance.transpose());
    }
}

Here's the B matrix that I want to calculate, but can't figure out how


Details

Particle: has the position (x) and velocity (v) of a particle.

Spring: has a vector of pointers to Particles and a damping coefficient (b).

System: Contains vectors of Springs and Particles, and computes the derivative of forces with respect to velocities (get_dfdv).

get_dfdv: Computes the matrix dfdv for the entire system. The size of dfdv is 3n x 3n, where n is the number of particles, since each particle has 3 velocity components (x, y, z).


For every spring in the system:

We compute the distance in between the two particles connected by the spring.

We then normalize the distance (norm_dist).

We compute beta_ij using the damping coefficient and the product of norm_dist.

We determine the indices of the particles in the system's particle vector.

We finally update the dfdv matrix by adding and subtracting beta_ij.


Code
#include <eigen3/Eigen/Dense>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

class Particle
{
public:
    Eigen::Vector3f x;
    Eigen::Vector3f v;
};

class Spring
{
public:
    std::vector<Particle *> particles;
    float b;
};

class ParticleSystem
{
public:
    std::vector<Spring *> m_springs;
    std::vector<Particle *> m_particles;
    Eigen::MatrixXf get_dfdv();
};

Eigen::MatrixXf ParticleSystem::get_dfdv()
{
    int n = m_particles.size();
    Eigen::MatrixXf dfdv = Eigen::MatrixXf::Zero(3 * n, 3 * n);

    for (Spring *spring : m_springs)
    {
        Particle *p1 = spring->particles[0];
        Particle *p2 = spring->particles[1];

        Eigen::Vector3f dist = p2->x - p1->x;
        Eigen::Vector3f norm_dist = dist / dist.norm();

        Eigen::Matrix3f beta_ij = spring->b * (norm_dist * norm_dist.transpose());

        int i = std::distance(m_particles.begin(), std::find(m_particles.begin(), m_particles.end(), p1));
        int j = std::distance(m_particles.begin(), std::find(m_particles.begin(), m_particles.end(), p2));

        dfdv.block<3, 3>(3 * i, 3 * i) -= beta_ij;
        dfdv.block<3, 3>(3 * i, 3 * j) += beta_ij;
        dfdv.block<3, 3>(3 * j, 3 * i) += beta_ij;
        dfdv.block<3, 3>(3 * j, 3 * j) -= beta_ij;
    }

    return dfdv;
}

int main()
{
    ParticleSystem ps;

    Particle *p1 = new Particle();
    Particle *p2 = new Particle();
    Particle *p3 = new Particle();

    p1->x = Eigen::Vector3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    p2->x = Eigen::Vector3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    p3->x = Eigen::Vector3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);

    ps.m_particles.emplace_back(p1);
    ps.m_particles.emplace_back(p2);
    ps.m_particles.emplace_back(p3);

    Spring *s1 = new Spring();
    s1->particles.emplace_back(p1);
    s1->particles.emplace_back(p2);
    s1->b = 0.5;

    Spring *s2 = new Spring();
    s2->particles.emplace_back(p2);
    s2->particles.emplace_back(p3);
    s2->b = 0.5;

    ps.m_springs.emplace_back(s1);
    ps.m_springs.emplace_back(s2);

    Eigen::MatrixXf dfdv = ps.get_dfdv();

    std::cout << dfdv << "\n";

    delete p1;
    delete p2;
    delete p3;
    delete s1;
    delete s2;
}


Prints
 -0.5     0     0   0.5     0     0     0     0     0
    0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
    0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
  0.5     0     0 -0.75  0.25     0  0.25 -0.25     0
    0     0     0  0.25 -0.25     0 -0.25  0.25     0
    0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
    0     0     0  0.25 -0.25     0 -0.25  0.25     0
    0     0     0 -0.25  0.25     0  0.25 -0.25     0
    0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0

Note

The resulting Jacobian matrix is 9 by 9 since there are 3 particles in the exampled system, each with 3 degrees of freedom (x, y, z positions). Therefore, we have a total of 9 degrees of freedom.

Finite Difference Method

Jacobian Matrix

Finite Difference Schemes and Partial Differential Equations



I thought it's supposed to give me a 3x3 matrix at the end?

@user9132502 It is 3n by 3n, n being the number of particles. In case of 1 particle, the output is 3 by 3.
